# Making a calculator in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, calculator

I am self learning how to code using HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I am using Nitrous.io as my IDE and using Meteor. I was trying to follow along and use a calculator tutorial however I've decided that it might be best to simply try and make a simple calculator on my own. I am not sure however how to make the buttons communicate with each other, so when the user presses '1' '+' '1', it comes out as '2'. I will put my code below, if someone could explain it to me it would be very much appreciated. Thanks so much :)

Right now I have the buttons displayed on the web page, but I can't get them to communicate with each other.

**calculator.html**

```
<template name="calculator">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
          <button id="button1" class="btn {{button1class}} buttonKeypad">1 </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
          <button id="button2" class="btn {{button2class}} buttonKeypad">2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
          <button id="button3" class="btn {{button3class}} buttonKeypad">3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
          <button id="buttonPlus" class="btn btn-warning buttonKeypad">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
          <button id="button4" class="btn {{button4class}} buttonKeypad">4</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
          <button id="button5" class="btn {{button5class}}
```

etc etc. up to buttonKeypad 9.

**calculator.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Session.set("string", "");

  Session.set("button1class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("button2class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("button3class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("button4class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("button5class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("button6class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("button7class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("button8class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("button9class", "btn-default");
  Session.set("submitclass", "btn-warning");

Template.calculator.helpers( {
   "string" : function () { return Session.get("string")},
"button1class" : function () { return Session.get("button1class")},
"button2class" : function () { return Session.get("button2class")},
"button3class" : function () { return Session.get("button3class")},
"button4class" : function () { return Session.get("button4class")},
"button5class" : function () { return Session.get("button5class")},
"button6class" : function () { return Session.get("button6class")},
"button7class" : function () { return Session.get("button7class")},
"button8class" : function () { return Session.get("button8class")},
"button9class" : function () { return Session.get("button9class")},
});


Template.calculator.events( {
    "click button": function() {
      Session.set("button1class", "btn-default");
      Session.set("button2class", "btn-default");
      Session.set("button3class", "btn-default");
      Session.set("button4class", "btn-default");
      Session.set("button5class", "btn-default");
      Session.set("button6class", "btn-default");
      Session.set("button7class", "btn-default");
      Session.set("button8class", "btn-default");
      Session.set("button9class", "btn-default");
    },
    });


Template.calculator.events( {
  "click #button1" : function() {
  Session.set("button1class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"1");
  },
  "click #button2" : function() {
  Session.set("button2class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"2");
  },
  "click #button3" : function() {
  Session.set("button3class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"3");
  },
  "click #button4" : function() {
  Session.set("button4class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"4");
  },
  "click #button5" : function() {
  Session.set("button5class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"5");
  },
  "click #button6" : function() {
  Session.set("button6class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"6");
  },
  "click #button7" : function() {
  Session.set("button7class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"7");
  },
  "click #button8" : function() {
  Session.set("button8class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"8");
  },
  "click #button9" : function() {
  Session.set("button9class", "btn-primary");
  Session.set("string", Session.get("string")+"9");
  },

  });
```

Comment: I'll edit it to make it shorter, thanks :)

Comment: Let me know if it's still too long

Comment: Yes, it's way better. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your code is hugely more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need all those session variables to set the style of the calculator buttons, you can just use css classes. (ex `:hover` for mouse hover and `:active` for buttons that are being clicked).

If your calculator doesn't have parentheses, life is pretty simple. When the user is entering a series of numbers, put them in a buffer and show them on a screen. Once the user touches an operand (`+-*/`) then save the buffer (to a session variable for instance) along with the operand. Allow the user to enter more numbers. When they hit `=` or a new operand, evaluate the pending operation. Display the results.